# DNN Site Redirection

Tags: url, dotnetnuke

I am trying to migrate one html website into DNN. The problem I am facing is the URL. The old website had a URL like www.mywebsite/page.html and after migration it had become www.mywebsite/page .So when the user search for the old url it do not show up.I want that whenever the user enters any of the above url it should redirect me to www.mywebsite/page.
How to deal with the Site Redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1) You put a redirect in the HTML files, and put them in place, so that they redirect to the DNN pages (this is not the recommended option)

2) You add the URLs that you want a DNN page to respond to through the Page Settings in DNN when you configure pages. I believe they end up going into a TabURLS table, so you can add a couple, see the format of the data, and then do a bulk insert into the database for the rest of your pages/urls.

Chris

Comment: That setting do not take .html as the input

Comment: Hrmmm sorry about that.

Comment: might look at one of the DNN url rewriters on the store.dnnsoftware.com